# Object reference not set to an instance of an object asp.net , c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Hey guys i get this error when i try to assign CartID to a string. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks

```
private static string CartID
{
    get
    {
        HttpContext cont = HttpContext.Current;
        string id = cont.Request.Cookies["ShopCartID"].Value;

        if (cont.Request.Cookies["ShopCartID"] != null)
        {
            return id;
        }
        else
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ShopCartID", id);
            int days = 7;
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(days, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime expiration = currentDate.Add(timeSpan);
            cookie.Expires = expiration;
            cont.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return id.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `CartID` in your question (other than the class itself) so I will assume you mean `ShopCartID`.

`cont.Request.Cookies["ShopCartID"]` could return `null` if a cookie with that name doesn't exist. You can't call members (in this case, `Value`) on a `null` reference. You have to first check if the cookie is `null`:

```
HttpCookie cookie = cont.Request.Cookies["ShopCartID"];
string id = cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null;
```

**EDIT**

This pattern is so common that my repository of common code has this defined:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static TResult IfNotNull<TValue, TResult>(this TValue value, Func<TValue, TResult> @delegate)
        where TValue : class
    {
        if (@delegate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("delegate");
        }

        return value != null ? @delegate(value) : default(TResult);
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
string id = cont.Request.Cookies["ShopCartID"].IfNotNull(arg => arg.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now everything works just fine. The text book i follow is not very well written...

Comment: Annoyingly, the MSDN documentation for the Item[string] property of HttpCookieCollection does *not* say what will be returned if the cookie is not found. I had to dig through decompiled source code to discover that `null` can, indeed, be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your null check before accessing the cookie value. Currently, your code calls cont.Request.Cookies["ShopCartID"].Value, which will fail if the cookie isn't there.